# Question re Managing Daphne Processes in Django App Deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-channels, daphne, asgi

I'm in the process of deploying a Django application with Channels and Daphne on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I'm seeking some advice on managing the Daphne processes.

I understand that Elastic Beanstalk provides some level of process supervision, including automatic restarts and health checks. However, I'm wondering if this is sufficient for an ASGI server like Daphne.

My specific questions are:

Process Supervision on EBS: Does AWS Elastic Beanstalk's default process supervision robustly handle the needs of an application using Daphne, especially in scenarios of high WebSocket usage?

Need for Supervisor: In your experience, is it necessary or advantageous to use a process control system like Supervisor to manage Daphne processes on Elastic Beanstalk? Are there specific scenarios or configurations where Supervisor becomes crucial?

Best Practices: If anyone has experience deploying Django Channels with Daphne on Elastic Beanstalk, could you share any best practices, particularly regarding process management and ensuring WebSocket connection stability?

Any insights, experiences, or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. I want to ensure that I set up the most reliable and effective environment for my application.

Thank you in advance for your help!